# Html Form - route is wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using the FileUpload sample from the asp.net tutorials.  When I build it as a stand alone, it works fine.  However, whenever I try to add that functionality to a new MVC4 website, the routing is wrong.  I'm probably not explaining this well, so here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body

        // Read the form data and return an async task.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the form data.
        foreach(var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            var strings = provider.FormData.GetValues(key);
            if (strings != null) foreach(var val in strings)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", key, val));
            }
        }

        // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
        foreach(var file in provider.FileData)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Uploaded file: {0} ({1} bytes)\n", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length));
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString())
        };
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

Here is the page I'm using:

```
<div style="height:400px;">
<h3>File Upload</h3>
<form name="trip_search" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/upload">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="trip" value="round-trip"/>
        Round-Trip
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="trip" value="one-way"/>
        One-Way
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="nonstop" />
        Only show non-stop flights
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="airports" />
        Compare nearby airports
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="dates" />
        My travel dates are flexible
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="seat">Seating Preference</label>
        <select name="seat">
            <option value="aisle">Aisle</option>
            <option value="window">Window</option>
            <option value="center">Center</option>
            <option value="none">No Preference</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

</form>
```

When I directly navigate to `localhost:13927api/upload` I see a response from the web api method.  I've got the DefaultApi route registered in my WebApiConfig.

But when I'm on the page `localhost/Home/About` and I click on the submit button, it attempts to go to `localhost/Home/api/upload` - which does not exist.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The suggestion by Mario fixed my issue.  The action method on my form was not relative to the root.

```
action="api/upload" vs. action="/api/upload"
```

That fixes my problem.

A bit of elaboration on the issue:

When you are in the default path (say yoursite/Home/Index -> if that is your default), then the action="api/myaction" will work because the current path is still seen as the root of the website.  However, once you actually navigate to a path (say yoursite/Home/About), the current path is now under "Home" and so my missing "/" naturally was relative to my current path rather than the root.  This is why the samples work without the leading "/", because the view in question is the default view.

Comment: Your form `action="api/upload"` is not relative to the root. Try `action="/api/upload"` or use one of the helpers to specify the route.

Comment: Use @Html.BeginForm so that you can specify the controller.  What is wrong is that your current form action is sending you to the home controller.

Comment: @Mario - oh good grief...  relative to the root, how could I have not thought about that - it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the answer, if that can help others too:

Your form `action="api/upload"` is not relative to the root. Try `action="/api/upload"` or use one of the helpers to specify the route.